# How to write a query that retrieves 3 replies for each user in my users table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

i want to display three replies from each user i have in my users table, so for instance if i have 3 users and each of them had replied to lets say 10 messages, i want my query to only retrieve 9 replies and not all of the replies in my messages_reply table.

heres what i tried:

```
     $replyquery="select * 
     from messages_reply 
     LEFT JOIN users 
     ON messages_reply.from_id=users.id 
     GROUP BY messages_reply.id LIMIT 3";
```

i know that what i wrote means that bring me 3 replies only, so how do i bring 3 replies from each user in my users table?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many databases, you can use `row_number()` for this:

```
select *
from (
    select mr.*, u.*, row_number() over(partition by u.id order by mr.id desc) rn
    from messages_reply mr
    inner join users u on mr.from_id = u.id 
) t
where rn <= 3
```

If you are running MySQL < 8.0, as I suspect from the lax use of `group by` in your query:

```
select mr.*, u.*
from messages_reply mr
inner join users u on mr.from_id = u.id 
where mr.id >= (
    select mr1.id
    from messages_reply mr1
    where mr1.from_id = u.id 
    order by mr1.id desc
    limit 2, 1
)
```

This gives you the 3 message replies with the greatest `id` for each user.

Comment: i feel like your answer is correct, but can u tell me what 'rn' is?

Comment: @LitAnalysis: `rn` is the alias for the result of `row_number()`, that is computed in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Query not tested, just a concept

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM messages_reply
    WHERE from_id = users.id
    ORDER BY <your wanted order field> DESC
    LIMIT 3) replies
    ON users.id = replies.from_id
```